# Is there any difference between sudo password and the one I used to login?

Tags: password, sudo

I was under the impression that both the sudo password and the password that I use to login to Ubuntu are the same. But it happened that after logging into the system, tying the password in terminal followed by **su**, it raises **Authentication failure !** error. Aren't they the same ?

Comment: They are same..

Comment: What *exactly* did you type? `invalid password !` doesn't sound like a normal response from `sudo` (the standard English-language failure message is `Sorry, try again.`)

Comment: @steeldriver oops! i corrected the qn

Comment: "tying the password in terminal followed by sudo" Please provide the exact command and error. "followed"? I would assume "sudo" preseeds the command

Comment: @Rinzwind I typed su and then entered the password. But it says authentication error!

Comment: You need to use `sudo su`. `su` is for systems that use a "root" account and Debian styled systems (ie. Ubuntu) do not.

Comment: @steeldriver Adding the line `Defaults insults` to your `/etc/sudoers` file will make the output on mistyped passwords much more interesting... **;-D**

Comment: @Pilot6 they are not. Read my answer

Answer (score 11):

`sudo`, by default, asks for *your* password, which is the password you use to login. On the other hand `su` ask for the password of the *target user* which, unless specified, defaults to root. Note that by default Ubuntu has an invalid password field set for root, effectively making it impossible to login as root.

Comment: I *think* the password field is just blank; I can't check my `/etc/passwd` file because it's unreliable as I've previously set / deleted root's password, however `sudo grep ^root /etc/shadow` should clarify

Comment: @kos According to `man shadow` after setting an empty password field "*no passwords are required to authenticate as the specified login name.*"

Comment: That might be overcome by the tool using `/etc/shadow`, in fact I just deleted my user's password with `sudo passwd -d` and I can't login using `su` without password; what happens when one tries to login using `su` really is ultimately up to `su` (where `su`'s scope can span obviously)

Comment: @kos This is true - settings of pam_unix do change the default behaviour. By default in ubuntu using the command you executed should still let you login using the console.

Answer (score 4):

> I was under the impression that both the sudo password and the password that I use to login to Ubuntu are the same.

They are.

If you want a root prompt you need to type

```
sudo -i
```

when using the admin account. Mind though: there are not a lot of situations where you should need to use a root prompt and it is more likely you want to do something not the Ubuntu way.

Example (in order: "su", wrong password using "sudo su", correct password):

```
:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for xxxxx:
Sorry, try again.    
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
:/home/xxxxx#
```

- Ubuntu does not have a "root" account (or better: it has been disabled). So "su" does not work since that is tied to the "root" account. "sudo -i" is tied to your admin user and will work.

Comment: Is `sudo su` the same as `sudo -i`?

Comment: The reason why `su` fails is because it expects the root password, and not the user's password; nonetheless passwordless root login through `su` is disabled for obvious reasons, so the only way to login as root through `su` is to set root a password

Comment: @ByteCommander no, [`sudo su` is the same as `sudo -s` and `sudo -i` is the same as `sudo su -`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su).

Comment: Rectifying: [passwordless login using `su` seems disabled for any user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/681730/is-there-any-difference-between-sudo-password-and-the-one-i-used-to-login/681739#comment990674_681739)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `sudo` (usually some command following it) it will ask you your login password, and you will gain `root` privilege.

when you use `su` you will be asked `root` user password (this is not the same as your login password unless you want it to be which is not recommended)

Usually, `root` user password is not set by default in Ubuntu on fresh install (in fedora you are asked to set `root` user password during installation). You have to set, only if you want to, `root` user password after installation.

Here is how you do it:

```
sudo -i
```

enter your login password and you will get something like this:

```
root@computer:/home/edward#
```

now type:

```
passwd
```

now you will be asked to set `root` user password.

So they  are different thing.

Comment: Or even just `sudo passwd`

Answer (score -1):

Your username password and sudo password initially the same unless you change them.You can change the root user password using this command from the terminal

```
sudo password [username] (for example , root)
```

```
sudo -i
```

```
sudo passwd root
```

You should be able to login to root using `sudo su` from the terminal and then use your password.
Hope that works for you.

Comment: "Your username password and sudo password [are] initially the same". They are *always* the same.